# Scaladocs: Reference values of enums

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scaladoc

In Scala, if I have an Enumeration like this:

```
package myPackage.letters

object Alphabet extends Enumeration {
  val A: Value = Value("A")
  val B: Value = Value("B")
  val C: Value = Value("C")
}
```

Now, I want to write a [ScalaDoc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/scaladoc.html) for a method in another package and reference the values of my Enum like this:

```
/**
  * Here, I want to reference my enum:
  * this works: [[myPackage.letters.Alphabet]]
  * this does not: [[myPackage.letters.Alphabet.A]]
  */
def myMethod = {}
```

Is this maybe an IntelliJ specific problem? Anyway I cannot seem to figure out how to correctly reference enum values or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: `[[myPackage.letters.Alphabet#A]]`

Comment: I will :) "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"